# What is the benefit of adding zeros subcarriers in frequency-domain OFDM signal?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

I have noticed in some OFDM systems, some null subcarriers are added in frequency domain. What's the benefit of those zero subcarriers, and is that mandatory ?

An example I have read about that adding of zero subcarriers is here [This paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6184288/citations?tabFilter=papers#citations)

Comment: I believe the question has been addressed at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/40341/26081

Comment: @AlexTP Thank you, Is inserting zero subcarriers mandatory in all cases ? or it's optional ? ..

Comment: It depends on your criteria. For example as answered in the link, it is mandatory for device production cost savings. It can be optional if you don't care about causing interference to other channels and cost is not your concern.